# What does the word contribution mean in contracts?

Tags: united-kingdom, workplace

What does the word contribution mean in
the following statement:

> The position would be subject to a contract and would come with a contribution of £1000 GBP per annum, understood as a contribution to expenses incurred in the role.

Does this mean that the company would pay the employee 1000 GBP per year for the work he/she does for them? I’d appreciate your thoughts on this.